# Django query objects with all related objects meeting a condition

Tags: django, orm, model

Given these Django models:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    pass

class Task(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', related_name='tasks')
    status = models.CharField(choices=TaskStatus.CHOICES, max_length=30)
    dependencies = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="dependents", symmetrical=False)
```

I want to query all Tasks with status PENDING and **ALL dependencies having status COMPLETED** for a single Job.

I wrote the following query, but it returns tasks that have at least one dependency with status completed, which is obviously not want I'm after.

```
tasks_that_can_be_executed = Task.objects.filter(
    job__pk=job_id,
    status=TaskStatus.PENDING,
    dependencies__status=TaskStatus.COMPLETED
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is status Column?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare added it. Sorry, I must have missed it when stripping out unrelated code for this example.

Comment: Why all are using `Q` I don't know it mostly use when we need to work with conditions? and filter always work with `AND`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Case, When, Count, Q

Task.objects.filter(
    job=job,
    status=TaskStatus.PENDING,
).annotate(
    not_completed_dependencies_count=Count(
        Case(When(~Q(dependencies__status=TaskStatus.COMPLETED), then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField(),
        )
    )
).filter(
    not_completed_dependencies_count__gt=0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Q from django.db.models you can make some more complex queries.
If I'm understanding you right, you want to

```
from django.db.models import Q

tasks_that_can_be_executed = Task.objects.filter(job__pk=job_id).filter(
        Q(status=TaskStatus.PENDING) | Q(dependencies__status=TaskStatus.COMPLETED)
)
```

Not sure I understood properly what you wanted as result, but in the current situation you will get all tasks from the given job_id, where the `status` is `PENDING` together with all objects where `dependencies__status` is `COMPLETED`

Comment: Almost! I only want tasks where ALL dependencies are completed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the ManyToMany. I'm still searching too, but I can't find somehting satisfying yet to keep it short and in one query.

Comment: Neither can I. I managed to implement a workaround by filtering out afterwards... but I would rather push it into the query :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exclude()` instead or in combination with `filter()`, as the `exclude()` would just throw away any result with a `status != COMPLETED`

```py
tasks_that_can_be_executed = Task.objects.filter(
    job__pk=job_id,
    status=TaskStatus.PENDING,
).exclude(
    dependencies__status=TaskStatus.PENDING
)
```

Or if there are multiple `status` values you like to exclude:

```py
tasks_that_can_be_executed = Task.objects.filter(
    job__pk=job_id,
    status=TaskStatus.PENDING,
).exclude(
    dependencies__status__in=[s for s in TaskStatus.CHOICES if s != TaskStatus.COMPLETED]
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to import Q
and then do something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

tasks_that_can_be_executed = Task.objects.filter(
    Q(job__pk=job_id) & Q(status=TaskStatus.PENDING) & Q(dependencies__status=TaskStatus.COMPLETED)
)
```

Comment: It seems you just rewrote author's filtering with Q objects. It's not like he wants.